# Any fast way to select a maximal subset that satisfies several inequality constraints?

Tags: constraints, subset

So I have a set of vectors in a 2D plane (in this case, pixels), and I need to select a maximal (longest) subset of these vectors, subject to three constraints: x_i - x_j <= a, y_i - y_j <= a for all i != j and some user-defined threshold a, and the spectral angle between each pair of distinct pixels <= b, for some other threshold b. Basically, the cosine distance between the vectors representing the spectral data of each pixel (which is, specifically, the arccos of the normalized dot product).

Whenever I see subset, I automatically think exponential time complexity, but there must be a way to take advantage of the constraints, right?